# UDK DLLBind how to

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'm trying to use UDK's DLLBind feature in UDK version 9953.
To start out, I've downloaded the DLLBind_Example project from http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DLLBind.html

I've built the dll and placed it in *UDK root*\Binaries\Win32\UserCode
I've copied the UnrealScript classes into *UDK root*\Developement\Src\MyMod\Classes

Next, the ReadMe file that came with the example says I need to edit UTGame\Config\UTEngine.ini to remove the semicolon from the line that says ModEditPackages=MyMod.

However, that file does not exist in my UDK.

Can anyone tell me what the equivalent is in the latest UDK version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The file you have to edit is UDK root\UDKGame\Config\UDKEngine.ini.
There is no commented out `ModEditPackages=MyMod` line in the file already, so you have to add it to the [UnrealEd.EditorEngine] section.